# git pull source tree

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree, pull

I need to pull master into recette branch. When I try (select recette branch click on pull select master on distant branch) the source tree tells me I'm already up to date but I'm not.

But when I right click on diff current there is a lot of diff.

I don't understand this issue someone can help me please?

[image: before pull]

[image: result]

Comment: Diff shows changes that you've made locally, even when you're up-to-date with origin.

Answer (score 0):

Read about [`git pull`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull). The last paragraph on the [DESCRIPTION](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#_description) section explains (the emphasis is mine):

> If any of the remote changes overlap with local uncommitted changes, the merge will be automatically canceled and the work tree untouched. *It is generally best to get any local changes in working order before pulling or stash them away with [git-stash](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull)*.

Comment: thanks i understand,
And there is a solution ?
Maybe merge request on git web ?